# Facebook Custom Conversion: How to set a conversion event equal to number of pages viewed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel, conversion-tracking

How do you create a custom conversion event for user engagement such that a "success" equals a user who has viewed more than a specific number of pageviews?

For example, the custom conversion event should be triggered when a user views *any* 20 or more pages, but not a specific page or pages.

This conversion event is described in this article (https://www.facebook.com/business/success/topix) but there appears to be no option in the actual custom conversion setup to achieve this. It's clear how to set up an event for users who view one pageview or a specific page, but not for a "number of pages viewed" goal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of number of pages via `cookie` and trigger specific event when count reaches 20 or your desired number.